# Is there a Ternary Operator in python

Tags: python, django, conditional-operator

I'm trying to do a ternary like operator for python to check if my dictionary value exist then use it or else leave it blank, for example in the code below I want to get the value of `creator` and `assignee`, if the value doesn't exist I want it to be `''` if theres a way to use ternary operator in python?

Here's my code :

```
        in_progress_response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, auth=auth).json()
        issue_list = []
        for issue in in_progress_response['issues'] :
            # return HttpResponse( json.dumps( issue['fields']['creator']['displayName'] ) )
            issue_list.append(
                            {
                                "id": issue['id'],
                                "key": issue['key'],
                                # DOESN'T WORK
                                "creator": issue['fields']['creator']['displayName'] ? '',
                                "is_creator_active": issue['fields']['creator']['active'] ? '',
                                "assignee": issue['fields']['assignee']['displayName'] ? '', 
                                "is_assignee_active": issue['fields']['assignee']['active'] ? '',
                                "updated": issue['fields']['updated'],
                            }
            )

         return issue_list
```

Comment: `issue["fields"].get("creator","")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Comment: Python's ternary operator is `value1 if cond else value2`, but use `dict.get` here.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operators in python act as follows:

```
condition = True
foo = 3.14 if condition else 0
```

But for your particular use case, you should consider using `dict.get()`. The first argument specifies what you are trying to access, and the second argument specifies a default return value if the key does not exist in the dictionary.

```
some_dict = {'a' : 1}

foo = some_dict.get('a', '') # foo is 1
bar = some_dict.get('b', '') # bar is ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, my `assignee` is `null`, when I do set it to this 

`"assignee": issue['fields']['assignee'].get("displayName","")`
I get this error : 
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to try to fetch an item from a dictionary and return an optional default value in case the dictionary does not contain the given key, you thus can implement this as:

```
"creator": issue.get('fields', {}).get('creator', {}).get('displayName', ''),
```

the same with the other items.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use something like ternary then
you can say

```
value = issue['fields']['creator']['displayName'] if issue['fields']['creator'] else ""
```